# Deployment Issue: Adding Static Page to Vercel/commerce App Without Shopify CMS API

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I'm trying to create static pages (I don't want to use the CMS; it's hard to layout as I want). In development, everything works but upon deployment I get this error: 'Application error: a client-side exception has occurred (see the browser console for more information).' Digest: 898870660. Does anyone have an idea?
https://github.com/vercel/commerce

I am attempting to add a new static page to my application without using the Shopify CMS API. Everything is working fine on my local build as well as in Vercel.

Here's the process I've followed:

1. I cloned the repository from https://github.com/vercel/commerce.
2. In the application directory, I removed the existing '[page]' folder.
3. I then created a new folder named 'ma-page'.
4. I added a 'page.tsx' file into this 'ma-page' folder.

While this setup works perfectly in the development environment, I'm encountering difficulties when attempting to deploy.